# I don't understand how のに　is used in this sentence 始めるのに遅すぎることはない。

Tags: grammar, particle-の

Supposedly this sentence means something like "It's never too late to start". But from what I learned のに　should mean "in order to". So I'd think the sentence means "In order not to be too late we need to start". Is there some grammatical explanation?

Comment: Hint: the のに in your sentence modifies 始める, so how do you think that should change your English translation?

Comment: It is good that you got a satisfying answer, but it doesn’t seem to remove the cause of your confusion. When のに means “in order to …,” what comes after “to” (i.e. the purpose) is expressed by the part **before** のに.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, の works as a noun, similarly to こと. Therefore, 始めるの means "starting (something)" in this sentence. Divide the sentence as : 始めるの/に/遅すぎること/は/ない.